# Connecting to USBTMC devices via USB in Linux

Tags: go, usb, libusb, visa

I'm currently implementing a gotmc/VISA package to send SCPI commands to my multimeter.

But every time I try to connect to the device, it gets me the same message:

> libusb: device or resource busy [code -6].

Is there a way to handle this problem?
From one source I read, I need to detach the kernel from the device, but can I do it from this package?

If there is another package that support SCPI commands over USB I would be grateful of hearing about it.

Here is my example code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "time"

    _ "github.com/gotmc/usbtmc/driver/google"
    "github.com/gotmc/visa"
    _ "github.com/gotmc/visa/driver/usbtmc"
)
const (
    usbAddress string = "USB0::10893::4610::MY58130019::INSTR"
)

func main() {
    fg, err := visa.NewResource(usbAddress)
    usbtmc.De
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Couldn't open the resource for the function generator")
    }
}
```

Comment: Use USB 3 ports instead of USB 2 ports? Turn ***OFF*** USB legacy support in the BIOS?

Comment: Can you add the output of `dmesg | tail -n 20` right after the device has been connected? (Add it to your question by editing your question - the "edit" link to the right of the "share" link.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few things to try:

1. The line `usbtmc.De` appears to be incomplete or a typo in your example code. Could you please provide the full line?
2. Confirm that the VISA address string you're using is correct for your multimeter.
3. There have been some updates to the [gotmc/usbtmc](https://github.com/gotmc/usbtmc) project since this question was asked, so I'd recommend using v0.4.0 or newer in your `go.mod`.
4. Eliminate [gotmc/visa](https://github.com/gotmc/visa) for now while trying to debug.
5. Enable USB debugging as shown in the code below and running the program using USB debug level 4.
6. Try using `NewDeviceByVIDPID()` instead of using `NewDevice()`.
7. What's the Keysight model number of the multimeter?

#### Command to run with USB level 4 debug

```sh
$ ./myprogram -d=4
```

#### go.mod

```
module github.com/myproj/myrepo

go 1.12

github.com/gotmc/usbtmc v0.4.0
```

#### main.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/gotmc/usbtmc"
    _ "github.com/gotmc/usbtmc/driver/google"
)

var (
    debugLevel uint
)

func init() {
    const (
        defaultLevel = 1
        debugUsage   = "USB debug level"
    )
    flag.UintVar(&debugLevel, "debug", defaultLevel, debugUsage)
    flag.UintVar(&debugLevel, "d", defaultLevel, debugUsage+" (shorthand)")
}

func main() {
    // Parse the config flags to determine the config JSON filename
    flag.Parse()

    // Create new USBTMC context and new device.
    start := time.Now()
    ctx, err := usbtmc.NewContext()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error creating new USB context: %s", err)
    }
    ctx.SetDebugLevel(int(debugLevel))

    mm, err := ctx.NewDevice("USB0::10893::4610::MY58130019::INSTR")
    // You could try the following instead:
    // mm, err := ctx.NewDeviceByVIDPID(10893, 4610)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("NewDevice error: %s", err)
    }
    log.Printf("%.2fs to create new device.", time.Since(start).Seconds())
    
    // Send a SCPI command to the multimeter.
    mm.WriteString("*CLS\n")

    // Close the multimeter and USBTMC context and check for errors.
    err = mm.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("error closing mm: %s", err)
    }
    err = ctx.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error closing context: %s", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: The questions belong in comments to the question. This is not a forum.